# how to take input from php and execute it in a command-line program in terminal linux

Tags: command-line, bash, php

i cant take an input enter by a user to load the input in a Linux terminal to execute it in a command line program...can you help please...for example when a user enter a value and press enter in must open terminal in the background and take the input and execute it in a command line program

Answer (score 0):

Start by using shell_exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php and any of the other Program execution Functions. Have a good read through the comments also.

Using a bit of AJAX could emulate a basic terminal if you don't want to reload the page each time.

Should also be careful what commands can be sent since letting anyone run these commands is a big security risk.